# problemas con un disco externo que no es leido

Tags: linux, windows, formato

Tengo un disco extrerno de 1TB pero windows solo lo ve como un disco sin letra..y no me deja darle formato al disco[image: iamgen del disco en windwos]

Pensando que solo era un problema con los archivos de windows lo probe en un ubuntu y basicamente dice que no se puede montar el disco...[image: imagen del disco en ubuntu] primero probe en la version de prueba y luego en un ubuntu ya instalado pero dio el mismo error.

Hay forma de salvar el disco duro o al menos la informacion?

Comment: ¿y que tiene que ver esto con programación?

Comment: Muy buenas, creo que este tipo de preguntas no entran dentro del ámbito de la comunidad SOes.

Comment: He visto este tipo de preguntas en Stack Overflow y allá no las cierran ni las votan en contra. No veo por qué acá tenemos que ser más papistas que el Papa

Comment: @amenadiel,  no se trata de ser fundamentalistas creo que la temática del sitio esta bien clara en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic y está no parece ser una pregunta que cuadre del todo bien con dicha temática. Hace tiempo atrás se discutió en meta este tema, por que la duda estaba en si podíamos considerar al hardware o al software como herramienta de desarrollo, por lo cual este tipo de pregunta podría tener validez, pero en ese momento el consenso fue que sería forzar demasiado el concepto de herramienta.

Comment: Este es el enlace de meta que te mencioné: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3336/son-v%C3%A1lidas-las-preguntas-sobre-instalaci%C3%B3n-de-sistemas-operativos

Comment: @PatricioMoracho lamento no haber participado de ese Meta, pero si te fijas, se define que preguntas que en inglés irían en SuperUser y ServerFault sí caben en este sitio. Creo que cae en una zona gris. Lo que sí puedo decir a favor de la pregunta es que no se trata de hardware, sino de las herramientas de software que se pueden usar para abordar el problema. Claramente no está preguntando sobre condensadores quemados en el disco

Comment: @amenadiel, así como está planteada, la pregunta es muy genérica y ambigua para saber si podría corresponder siquiera a la temática de ServerFault, todo lo que se puede deducir es un OP que tiene un problema con un disco externo, ¿Es el disco de una base de datos o dónde guarda su colección de películas?. Por mi parte creo que no es de la temática del sitio como ya opinaron otros usuarios, pero en última instancia la que decide es la comunidad. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho entiendo tu punto. En ese caso, el canal formal es votar para cerrar la pregunta o bien reportarla. Como mi interpretación es que la pregunta toca tangencialmente los temas de este sitio, me pareció apropiado responder.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que podrías probar y ninguna garantiza el éxito. Antes de hacer un reformateo forzado, si te interesa la información del dísco, yo probaría:

Listando las particiones del disco con

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
```

Ahí listará las particiones y podrás saber cuál es la `sdc2`. Aparentemente es la de 931GB.

También puedes hacer caso a la sugerencia que te da ubuntu y ejecutar

```
dmesg | tail
```

Que debiera darte algo como:

```
[446381.305612] usb-storage 3-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[446381.305755] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-3:1.0
[446382.333291] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[446382.334626] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 62530624 512-byte logical blocks: (1000.0 GB/991 GiB)
[446382.335386] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[446382.335389] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[446382.335619] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[446382.357324]  sdc: sdc1
[446382.358324]  sdc: sdc2
[446382.358734] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Pero con más información acerca del error.

Para saber el tipo de partición, puedes ejecutar:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdc
```

Que te llevará a un prompt donde dice:

```
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted)
```

Ahí presionas `p` para que imprima la información del disco. Debiera decirte algo como:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  201MB  200MB    primary  EFI          boot
 2      201MB   932GB  931GB    primary  msdos
```

Con esa información (sabiendo que sdc2 es de tipo `msdos`) podrías intentar

```
sudo mkdir /mnt
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/sdc2 /mnt
```

Si nada de eso resulta, vas a tener que intentar reformatear el disco. Mira esta respuesta: https://askubuntu.com/questions/769079/cant-format-ubuntu-installation-stick/769094

Comment: bueno me dio una idea de que le pasa dice que no se puede montar bien por el sistema de archivos

Comment: Me sirvio lo que me dijiste ahora se que algo no se monto bien
[ 136.748418] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953504688 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[ 136.748760] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 136.748766] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 27 00 00 00
[ 136.749011] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 136.749017] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 136.814586] sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[ 136.815644] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[ 137.263542] hfsplus: Filesystem was not cleanly unmounted, running fsck.hfsplus is recommended. mounting read-only.

Comment: [ 137.263779] hfsplus: invalid extent max_key_len 0 
[ 137.263786] hfsplus: failed to load extents file esto sale despies del dmesg tail

Comment: hfsplus? Acaso el disco se usó en OSX?